# Remove certain words from string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with a column containing string. I have another dataframe df2 with 1 column (so it can be a serie) which contains 1 word each row.

I would like to remove all the words from df that are in df2.
Example:

```
  df:

           ColString
0     I would like to buy apples.


df2:
         Wordlist
0          like
1         apples
```

Result:

```
  df:

           ColString
0     I would to buy .
```

Any ideas ?  Thanks for help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `replace` with `regex=True`

```
df1.col.replace(df2.Wordlist.str.cat(sep='|'),'',regex=True)
Out[510]: 
0    I would  to buy .
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: @hdatas yw : -) happy coding